# How to create message box when a value changes in a range based off a formula on a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a message box automatically when a cell on a separate worksheet equals 0 in column J.

The values in column J are calculated using a formula based off input values.

I tried using the intersection function and cannot get it to work when operating in a range that is not a specific cell.

Answer (score 0):

Worksheet_Change events only fire when a value is entered into a cell, not when a formula recalculates the value of a cell. You will need to hook the event to the data entry cell, then use code to check the values in column J for zeros.